# BIRT Reporting - Creating a hyperlink for each series label

Tags: birt

I have a bar chart containing Number of Faults in Y Axis, and Year-Month in X Axis.

Example Dataset:

Year-Month | Number of Faults

2013-01 - - - - 5

2013-02 - - - - 6

2013-03 - - - - 10

So in the chart, the labels for each bar would 5, 6 and 10.

How do I create a hyperlink for each label such that when you click the label of yearmonth 2013-01 which is "5", it will redirect you to a report that shows what those 5 faults are.

I hope I explained it well.
Thanks in advance!

EDIT1:
By the way I'm using eclispe, and BIRT report is integrated with Grails. Forgot to mention these specifics.

Answer (score 0):

Try this step :

1. Open your report (.rptdesign)
2. Right click to label -> properties
3. Choose Hyperlink tab
4. Click edit
5. In Select Hyperlink Type choose Drill-through
6. Set the report name and report parameter

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I cannot seem to find the label -> properties when right clicking. Im working on Eclipse by the way.